# Change menu font of wine program

Tags: fonts, menu, wine

I have successfully bottled a program with [WineBottler](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/documentation) to run on Mac OS X but the menu font size is way too small.  I have included Wine itself in that program since it's the only program I use it for.  I have changed the "screen resolution" setting in `winecfg` (in the wine bundle) but it only affects `winecfg` itself and not the program that wine is bundled in.  How can I make the program itself recognize the setting?

EDIT:
When I change the appearance in Wine, i.e., by running `winecfg` contained in the Wine.app and then run my program (*.exe) *through* Wine it takes all my appearance settings.  But when I bottle it with WineBottler it goes back to some default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WineBottler uses a dual approach when it comes to creating bottles: Bottle and working-copy: Since OS X will prevent some users from changing files in apps in the Application folder, WineBottler will create a mutable working-copy (~/Library/Application Support/BOTTLENAME) when it is first run.

So if you just alter the original generated bottle, it will not be reflected in the working copy.

To change a setting in a bottled App, you either have to

a) reset the bottled app and alter the created app with wine as you did (and the changes will be copied at next run to the newly generated working-copy)

b) you have to alter it in the working-copy, i.e. change the prefix of wine to the working-copy (~/Application Support/BOTTLENAME).

Comment: Wow, the man himself!  Thanks for the prompt reply. Let me give your suggestions a try.

Comment: Hmm, that didnt do it.  I tried suggestion (a):  Upon running `winecfg` (in the newly created app, i.e., `/path/to/app/myapp.app/Contents/Resources/Wine.bundle/Contents/Resources/bin/winecfg` I get a message that `.wine` is being created in my home folder.  So it seems that the settings are stored there and not in the app. :(  Any further suggestions?

Comment: Found a workaround:  I don't know if that's very elegant but it worked for me.  So it seems that the settings are stored in `user.reg`.  I have now made my modifications with `winecfg`. Then I copied the `user.reg` from the currently active prefix to my new app and replaced the one in the app in the `wineprefix` folder. Then I delete all the prefixes (both `.wine` and the one created in App Support) and start the app and yay it kept the settings!

Comment: :) - whatever works for you. Just for reference for a) and b) I meant to run winecfg with Wine.app. I.e. start Wine.app, click the WineGlass in the status bar-> click "Change prefix..." -> select the working copy -> again click the Wineglass in the statusbar -> click "Configuration" then alter the dpi in winecfg.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that.  The problem was that I would have had to change the prefix to the one that's included within my app, and for some reason Wine didn't see it – it only sees the prefix that is created in Application Support (and the default .wine). But after figuring out which file it was it was pretty straightforward. Anyways, thanks for your help — and for WineBottler!!

Answer (score 2):

Copying the whole **user.reg** works, but you want to be more specific.

The simpler way is to edit **~/.wine/user.reg** and set the following in **Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics**

```
"CaptionFont"=hex:ed,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,bc,02,00,00,\
  00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,54,00,61,00,68,00,6f,00,6d,00,61,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00

"MenuFont"=hex:f0,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,90,01,00,00,00,\
  00,00,01,00,00,00,00,54,00,61,00,68,00,6f,00,6d,00,61,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00

"IconFont"=hex:f0,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,90,01,00,00,00,\
  00,00,01,00,00,00,00,54,00,61,00,68,00,6f,00,6d,00,61,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00

"MessageFont"=hex:f0,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,90,01,00,00,\
  00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,54,00,61,00,68,00,6f,00,6d,00,61,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00

"SmCaptionFont"=hex:f3,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,bc,02,00,\
  00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,54,00,61,00,68,00,6f,00,6d,00,61,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00

"StatusFont"=hex:f5,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,90,01,00,00,00,\
  00,00,cc,00,00,00,00,54,00,61,00,68,00,6f,00,6d,00,61,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\              
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
```

(I assume you want all fonts bigger, if you only care about the menus, only edit menufont)

If the font is too big for you, use instead:

```
"CaptionFont"=hex:06,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,bc,02,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,22,54,00,61,00,68,00,6f,00,6d,00,61,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00

"MenuFont"=hex:06,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,90,01,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,22,54,00,61,00,68,00,6f,00,6d,00,61,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00

"MessageFont"=hex:06,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,90,01,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,22,54,00,61,00,68,00,6f,00,6d,00,61,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00

"StatusFont"=hex:06,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,90,01,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,22,54,00,61,00,68,00,6f,00,6d,00,61,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
```

(personally, the font was still hardly readable before on my high resolution screen, so I have to use the largest one)

Once you have fixed the fonts, in winecfg, if you change the DPI settings, the menu font will now grow in proportion.

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement the answer of Cha above I found these WindowMetrics work best on my MacBook Pro Retina 13" (late 2012) under Fedora 28 and Wine Staging 3.11 ...

```
"BorderWidth"="1"
"CaptionFont"=hex:08,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,bc,02,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,22,54,00,61,00,68,00,6f,00,6d,00,61,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"CaptionHeight"="-270"
"CaptionWidth"="-270"
"IconSpacing"="-1125"
"IconTitleWrap"="1"
"IconVerticalSpacing"="-1125"
"MenuFont"=hex:f5,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,90,01,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,54,00,61,00,68,00,6f,00,6d,00,61,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"MenuHeight"="-270"
"MenuWidth"="-270"
"MessageFont"=hex:08,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,90,01,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,22,54,00,61,00,68,00,6f,00,6d,00,61,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"PaddedBorderWidth"="0"
"ScrollHeight"="-240"
"ScrollWidth"="-240"
"Shell Icon Size"="32"
"SmCaptionFont"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,90,01,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,22,54,00,61,00,68,00,6f,00,6d,00,61,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"SmCaptionHeight"="-180"
"SmCaptionWidth"="-180"
"StatusFont"=hex:08,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,90,01,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,22,54,00,61,00,68,00,6f,00,6d,00,61,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
```

Caveat: Every new update of wine seems to destroy the manually set values and will insist on its default values.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be OK to directly change the following in user.reg (for example by writing a program that modifies user.reg):

```
[Software\\Wine\\Fonts]
"LogPixels"="dword:000080"
```

I have tried feeding the following script to regedit:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Hardware Profiles\Current\Software\Fonts]
"LogPixels"="dword:00000080"
```

but the change is ignored and the value in the Registry is unchanged when viewed with regedit. Is it possible to change the Registry this way?